# Make an ordering in a selection based on the presence of equal attribute in a set of other elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML structure like this:

```
<people>
  <person id="1" name="Sam" />
  <person id="2" name="Dan" />
</people>
<executives>
  <executive id="1" name="Sam" favorite="yes" />
  <executive id="3" name="Ian" />
</executives>
```

I need to reference all nodes in *people*, but I need to first go through those that have a favorites property in *executives*, then the rest. I guess I need to somehow combine `<xsl:apply-templates select="/people/person[/executives/executive/@id = @id]" />`
and `<xsl:apply-templates select="/people/person[@favorite = 'yes']" />`.

But I don't know how.

Comment: In your example code you have both `/people` and `/executive`, but only one element can be rooted, unless this is a dynamically created document, i.e. in a variable, but that is more common in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You should post your expected result; "*go through*" can be read in so many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following would work:

```
<!-- your root here, which you didn't show in the question -->
<xsl:template match="/root">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="people" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="people">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="person" mode="fav"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="person" mode="other"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person[@id = ../../executives/executive[@favorite = 'yes']/@id]" mode="fav">
    <favorite>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <favorite>
</xsl:template>

<!-- not a favorite -->
<xsl:template match="person" mode="fav" />

<!-- not a non-favorite -->
<xsl:template match="person" mode="other" />

<xsl:template match="person[not(@id = ../../executives/executive[@favorite = 'yes']/@id)]" mode="other">
    <non-favorite>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <non-favorite>
</xsl:template>
```

There are better ways to write this using keys (a solution as such has meanwhile been given by Tim), but I think this suffices, unless you have insanely large lists that make the direct lookups too slow.

The structure I used for the output should be adjusted to whatever you require. I used the extra elements to make sure you collect the right ones.

Comment: Thanks! `person[@id = ../../executives/executive[@favorite = 'yes']/@id]` was what I was looking for!

Comment: @Anna, glad it helped, but when things get more complex, consider the other solutions, which are easier to maintain in the long run (using keys).

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially simplify things by using a key to look up the executives by the `name` attribute

```
<xsl:key name="execs" match="executive" use="@name" />
```

Then, to get the `person` nodes which have a favourite in executives, you can use the key like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="person[key('execs', @name)/@favorite = 'yes']" />
```

You would negate the condition to get the others.

Assuming you had a well-formed XML (i.e. with a root element), try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="execs" match="executive" use="@name" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <people>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//people" />
        </people>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="people">
        <favorites>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person[key('execs', @name)/@favorite = 'yes']" />
        </favorites>
        <other>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person[not(key('execs', @name)/@favorite = 'yes')]" />
        </other>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I agree, using keys is effectively simpler (compare my code...), +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way to look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="x" match="executive" use="@id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="people">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="person">
            <xsl:sort select="number(key('x', @id)/@favorite='yes')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input**

```
<root>
    <people>
      <person id="1" name="Adam" />
      <person id="2" name="Betty" />
      <person id="4" name="David" />
      <person id="5" name="Eve" />
      <person id="6" name="Frank" />
      <person id="7" name="George" />
    </people>
    <executives>
      <executive id="3" name="Cecil" favorite="yes" />
      <executive id="5" name="Eve" />
      <executive id="6" name="Frank" favorite="yes" />
    </executives>
</root>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <people>
      <person id="6" name="Frank"/>
      <person id="1" name="Adam"/>
      <person id="2" name="Betty"/>
      <person id="4" name="David"/>
      <person id="5" name="Eve"/>
      <person id="7" name="George"/>
   </people>
   <executives>
      <executive id="3" name="Cecil" favorite="yes"/>
      <executive id="5" name="Eve"/>
      <executive id="6" name="Frank" favorite="yes"/>
   </executives>
</root>
```

Comment: Nice trick, using boolean order through `number(key('x', @id)/@favorite='yes')` to get the nodes in one go and in order. Not sure it'll be clear right away for the casual reader though...